# Problem with whitespace within InfoPath Web Part

Tags: web-part, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that I've created and inserted on a SharePoint page via an InfoPath Web Part.  When I insert the form it does not fit flush edge to edge within the web part, there is white space all around it.  I tried resizing the form, however, it only causes the web part and corresponding whitespace to also expand.  How can I get rid of this whitespace so the form displays properly on the page?

[image][image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the InfoPath Form as how it shows up in InfoPath Preview?

Comment: Added screen shot of what it looks like within preview in InfoPath

Comment: Is that grey border with the latin part of your form?

Comment: No that is the background of the page the web part was placed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can get it totally flush without modifying the CSS.  But we can get it closer and remove the white background.

1. Open the form in InfoPath Designer
2. Click in the white space outside of the table
3. Click the Align Left button in the Format Text section of the Home Ribbon.
   [image: List item]
4. Click the Page Design tab
5. Click the Properties button

   [image]
6. Check the box for "Use a background color" and select the color that matches your table background color.
7. Click OK and publish the form.

Please let me know if that works.